# Equivalent datatypes in flex for various wsdl data types?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, wsdl

WSDL defines a number of datatypes supported by web service . Is there a documentation stating the various equivalents of those datatypes on flex side. In general for any language that we use to consume web service, how do we get to know the equivalent datatypes of the wsdl types.

One of the web service that I am consuming is returning base64Binary (an image binary data) , 
What is the equivalent datatype of this on flex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see link

[Serializing between ActionScript and web services](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_2.html)

You can also define your custom type this link is for JAVA

[Explicitly mapping ActionScript and Java objects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html)

EDIT: This also very supportive link

[Using WebService components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdb.html)

hopes that helps

Answer (score 1):

base64Binary is a [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) (any binary based datatype is a ByteArray in Flash) and you can set the endian within the object.